# Visual Studio 2010 : change shortcut "delete whole line"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shortcut

I change from Eclipse to Visual Studio. I feel convenient when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will delete whole line.

I read a tip saying that to change the shortcut keyboard, go to : `Tool>Option>Keyboard`.

But when I go there, there are so many options, that I don't know which one changes shortcut for `delete whole line`.

@ : I'm using VS 2010, but at option :`apply the following addition keyboard mapping scheme` just has `C# 2005` that I think it should be `C# 2010`. Does it have any problems?

Thanks :)

Comment: Let the IDE do the work for you.  Type "delete" in the "Show commands containing" box and it filters the list down to the commands that delete something.  You'll have little trouble finding the correct command.  Also pay attention to the first word, "Edit" performs editing commands.

Comment: thanks for your advice. It will help me later :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't have time to test it but I believe `Edit.LineDelete` is the one you should look at. By default it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Also my Visual Studio 2010 only has C# 2005 as well so I guess these shortcuts haven't changed much in 7 years. :)

Comment: Applies also to 2012. You'd be looking for the mentioned Edit.LineDelete and applying it to the "Text Editor".

Comment: Thanks. I hate that shift+delete performs a cut and I always change it to do a simple delete. I always forget the name of the property though